# FCM Push notification not working in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I need to handle push notification and that's done with a lower version of ios but in ios 11 never receive any push notification. I using Firebase Cloud Messaging. please, anyone has a solution then please share.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please Check as 
[image]

[image]

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Use Firebase library to configure APIs
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    self.registerForPushNotifications(application: application)
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

    if let token = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
        NSLog("FCM TOKEN : \(token)")
        DataModel.sharedInstance.onSetUserFCMStringToken(FCM: token)
        self.connectToFcm()
    }
    if launchOptions != nil {
        //opened from a push notification when the app is closed
        _ = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [AnyHashable: Any] ?? [AnyHashable: Any]()
    }
    else {
        //opened app without a push notification.
    }
    return true
}
```

@available(iOS 10, *)

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
// iOS10+, called when presenting notification in foreground
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    NSLog("[UserNotificationCenter] willPresentNotification: \(userInfo)")
    //TODO: Handle foreground notification
    completionHandler([.alert])
}

// iOS10+, called when received response (default open, dismiss or custom action) for a notification
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    NSLog("[UserNotificationCenter] didReceiveResponse: \(userInfo)")
    //TODO: Handle background notification
    completionHandler()
}}

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
//MARK: FCM Token Refreshed
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    NSLog("[RemoteNotification] didRefreshRegistrationToken: \(fcmToken)")
}

// Receive data message on iOS 10 devices while app is in the foreground.
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    NSLog("remoteMessage: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
}}

//Register for push notification.
func registerForPushNotifications(application: UIApplication) {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.delegate = self
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert,.sound]) { (granted, error) in
            if error == nil{
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                })
            }
        }
    }
    else {

        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert,.sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }

    // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.InstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)

}

@objc func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    print(#function)
    if let refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
        NSLog("Notification: refresh token from FCM -> \(refreshedToken)")

    }
    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    connectToFcm()
}

func connectToFcm() {
    // Won't connect since there is no token
    guard InstanceID.instanceID().token() != nil else {
        NSLog("FCM: Token does not exist.")
        return
    }

    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    NSLog("Notification: Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}


// This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
// If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to the InstanceID token.
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {


    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken


}

// iOS9, called when presenting notification in foreground
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    NSLog("didReceiveRemoteNotification for iOS9: \(userInfo)")

}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {




}
```

Comment: hey , I am used  FirebaseInstanceID', "2.0.0" and even the latest pod , But didn't get the notification , Can you guide me , How t o fixes this

Comment: after lot of search i just used latest version or default version of pod and then checked thats work in my side there is certificate issues or some times FCM token issues plz check

Comment: Pem file I am using is working in other online portal . I have added in FCM but here It shows message been send , But I haven't received on my device . That the issue right now ,I am facing

Comment: you sending notification via fcm token or else?

Comment: yes , I am using that. Can you give me your Skype Id . Or message me at vijayvir.smartitventures@gmail.com

Comment: save my time bro

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems to be with

- FirebaseInstanceID Version less than  1.0.9
- FirebaseInstanceID Version between 2.0.1 - 2.0.3

Set your pod file as below :

**For Swift 2.3 and Xcode 8 :** (FirebaseInstanceID v1.1.0 gets installed)

```
pod 'Firebase/Core', '3.8.0'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

**For Swift 3 and Xcode 9 :**

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'FirebaseInstanceID', "2.0.0
```

I didn't want to upgrade to FirebaseInstanceID 2.0.0 to fix the issue as I wanted use Swift 2.3 only

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the issue was I was missing my APN configuration in firebase console.

Comment: Hi, you can not ask questions inside the answer. for if you are facing same issue then check answer else create new questions with your configuration.