# iOS FCM Push notifications not working in background state in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my application I have implemented FCM push notification. It is working fine When checking notification with FCM console and pushtry.com website, Then I tried with actual Server API the foreground notification works well, But   background notification not receiving and sometimes it receives very rarely and that too without banner and sound . Please help to find out the issue.

Here I attached the code what I am trying..

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
             didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
FirebaseApp.configure()

Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

    let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: {_, _ in })
} else {
    let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
}

application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
return true
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {

print(userInfo)
}
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication)
{
    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication)
{
    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = false
    print("Disconnected from FCM.")
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
             fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping 
(UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

print(userInfo)

completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \ . 
(error.localizedDescription)")
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")

}
}

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                        willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: 
@escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
  print(userInfo)

completionHandler([])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                        didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: 
@escaping () -> Void) {
let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
print(userInfo)

completionHandler()
}
}

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken 
fcmToken: String) {
  print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
}
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: 
MessagingRemoteMessage) {
  print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
}
}
```

Here I share the request format from server for push the notification:

```
{
"to":"cerGBjsmtzE:APA91bFk- 
 6ZI4ehaWbg0bGSGzAh10NeUh3AcyEFq7dASU7W4YY4WL8vWCA5wav- 
 LTYc0xTGWHev8Z99",
 "priority":"high",
"data":
  {
    "title":"New Inspection scheduled",
    "body":"You have a new Inspection Request scheduled,
    "sound":"default"
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FCM Push notification not working in iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47234355/fcm-push-notification-not-working-in-ios-11)

Comment: If you know the answer means please don't make as negative rating or duplicate please

Comment: But this is not my issue bro,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47234355/fcm-push-notification-not-working-in-ios-11..@KiranSarvaiya

Comment: Make sure you have enable the Remote notification in background mode --- In Capabilities section of XCODE.

Comment: B.Saravana Kumar, I already told that with duplication comment there is all info what you required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To receive the push notification in background mode there must be  `"mutable-content"` key with value `"1"` or `true` is present in your payload format.

Please tell you, backend developer, to add that key.
Please check following valid payload format

```
{
   "to": "dWB537Nz1GA:APA91bHIjJ5....",
   "content_available": true,
   "mutable_content": true,

   "data":
   {
      "message": "Offer!",
      "mediaUrl": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2a/FloorGoban.JPG/1024px-FloorGoban.JPG"
   },

   "notification":
   {
      "body": "Enter your message",
      "sound": "default"
   }
}
```

You can refer the following link
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: where I want to add that key bro.

Comment: Notification key also missing in your payload format

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: In backend they use key "data" instead of "Notification" that is correct request or not?

Comment: No, the data key is required for Android guys and notification for ios guys

Comment: Thanks, @HemantSabale  

Can you please let me know this format is correct? ->
     
 [AnyHashable("gcm.notification.type"): 0, AnyHashable("gcm.notification.msg"): {type":"Text","content":"Testing push from fcm"}, AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 0:1531784023250944%c52fb209c52fb209, AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1, AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert =     {
        body = "Testing push from fcm";
        title = "ip ";
    };
    badge = 2;
    "content-available" = 1;
}]

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have selected the Remote settings in background mode --- Under the capabilities section of XCODE

[image: Reference]