# Can not receive notification(fcm) on ios device from apple store

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, push

Why when I build the app on ios device is showing the message but when push the app to the apple store does not receive notification.

I have anable the push notification feature
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLToF.png)

*This is all code for the Appdelegate file*

Visit https://ideone.com/ErsdDS to see code

## code

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces
import CoreData
 
//import MessagingDelegate
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,MessagingDelegate {
    static var mangedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?
    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"
    let key = "AIzaSyDzuGKTfmkbR_VBffp....11Gz7pFOX2c"
 
 
//
//    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
//
//
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        ///
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyD2kiw....qFi-z2-iEzdcbvloSNOweBo")
        GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyD2ki....1qFi-z2-iEzdcbvloSNOweBo")
        // [START set_messaging_delegate]
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        // [END set_messaging_delegate]
        // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
        // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
 
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
 
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
 
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
 
 
        //
 
        AppDelegate.mangedObjectContext = persistentContainer.viewContext
        return true     
    }
 
 
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
 
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
 
    print(userInfo)
}
 
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ application: UIApplication) {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyD2kiwgq9e1qFi-z2-iEzdcbvloSNOweBo")
        // [START set_messaging_delegate]
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        // [END set_messaging_delegate]
        // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
        // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
 
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
 
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
 
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
 
 
 
    }
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
 
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
 
    print(userInfo)
 
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
 
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")
 
}
    func application(application: UIApplication,
                     didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken as Data
    }
 
    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }
 
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }
 
    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }
 
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }
 
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        /*
         The persistent container for the application. This implementation
         creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
         application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
         error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
         */
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Model")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
 
                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()
 
    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support
 
    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
 
}
 
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
 
    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
 
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
 
        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
 
        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([.alert,.sound])
    }
 
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
 
        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
        completionHandler()
    }
}
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
extension AppDelegate  {
    // [START refresh_token]
 
 
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
        InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching remote instange ID: \(error)")
            } else if let result = result {
                print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
                tokenfb = result.token
                print("tao dang tesst: \(tokenfb)")
 
        }
            saveCache(key: "tokenfb", value: tokenfb)
        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }
}
    // [END refresh_token]
    // [START ios_10_data_message]
    // Receive data messages on iOS 10+ directly from FCM (bypassing APNs) when the app is in the foreground.
    // To enable direct data messages, you can set Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel to true.
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }
    // [END ios_10_data_message]
}
```

*please help me!

Comment: Can you please check this questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47234355/fcm-push-notification-not-working-in-ios-11/47236517#47236517

Comment: @KiranSarvaiya yes. iam testing that solution . thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) 
{
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Sandbox)
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Prod)
}
```

> FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Sandbox used when we download it from TestFlight or when we are testing in development mode and FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Prod used when we release production build or when we download from AppStore

Comment: When I paste the above code into the error message
I've fixed it
//InstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .prod)

But it notifies instancelD () that the attribute is setAPNSToken
I just found a new way to save tokens starting with firebase 4.0
//Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: MessagingAPNSTokenType.prod)

I tried it on debug mode and was awaiting approval on the apple store to test its performance
I will report back to you the test results :))

Comment: @TrầnBìnhMinh sure :)

Comment: help me please !